# In m210 v2, video is not received according to the usb mode

Tags: video, usb, manifold

m210 v1 and v2 are great products. However, there are some problems when used with manifold2.

On m210 V2(RTK, nonRTK both), The problem I encountered is that depending on the USB mode, the video(x5s) cannot be received at crystal-sky display.

[ref image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpZ3M.jpg)

1.When changing the USB mode to PC mode using the slide switch, manifold can detect m210 USB / but, video from gimbal camera(x5s) not display on crystal-sky display with ERROR 'sd card is not enough'

2. If setting the USB mode to mobile mode,
   manifold can not detect m210 USB / video display on crysta-sky display

but, on m210 V1 with same manifold it didn't happened.

Even if you connect the m210 and the computer (Linux), it happens again.
ofcourse i activated every flights, update firmwares/apps,  enable USB port to fly. there are enought volumes in SD card.

Are there any solutions to solve this USB mode problem???